Flutter & Django : How do we authenticate user by JWT?
I'm developing authentication pages for my app using Flutter for the mobile frontend and Django for the backend.
The login functionality works perfectly, but I'm encountering an issue with the logout process. When I try to log out, it returns a "forbidden" error, indicating that the user is not authenticated.
I suspect the issue might be related to how I'm setting the jwt in the headers for the HTTP requests in Flutter.
Could someone please take a look and help me troubleshoot this?
Thank you!
Flutter
class AuthService {
  // Base URL for the user endpoints
  final String _loginUrl = '$BASE_URL/users/login';
  final String _isLoggedInUrl = '$BASE_URL/users/is_logged_in';
  final String _logoutUrl = '$BASE_URL/users/logout';

  Future<String?> login(String email, String password) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(_loginUrl),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: json.encode({'email': email, 'password': password}),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Store the JWT token in shared preferences
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final token = json.decode(response.body)['jwt'];
      await prefs.setString('jwt', token);
      return token;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to login');
    }
  }

  Future<bool> isLoggedIn() async {
    print("In isLoggedIn");
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final token = prefs.getString('jwt');

    // If token is null, the user is not logged in
    if (token == null) {
      return false;
    }

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(_isLoggedInUrl),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );

    // Check response status and print for debugging
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final sth = json.decode(response.body);
      print(sth);
      return true; // User is logged in if the response is successful
    } else {
      return false; // User is not logged in if the response fails
    }
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.remove('jwt'); // Remove JWT from shared preferences

    // Optionally call the logout API
    final token = prefs.getString('jwt'); // Get the token for logout request
    await http.post(
      Uri.parse(_logoutUrl),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token', // Include token if required
      },
    );
  }
}

Django
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
import jwt
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from users.models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from .authentication import JWTAuthentication

# Helper function to generate JWT tokens
def generate_jwt(user):
    print("Generating JWT token for user:", user.email)
    payload = {
        'id': user.id,
        'exp': datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(minutes=60),
        'iat': datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    }
    token = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
    return token

# View for user registration
class RegisterView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        print("Inside RegisterView: Registering user")
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()

        # Generate JWT token for the new user
        token = generate_jwt(user)

        response = Response(
            {'status': 'success', 'jwt': token}, 
            status=201
        )
        response.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True)
        print("User registered successfully and JWT token set in cookie")
        return response

# View for user login
class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        print("Inside LoginView: Logging in user")
        email = request.data.get('email')
        password = request.data.get('password')

        user = get_object_or_404(User, email=email)

        if not user.check_password(password):
            print("Incorrect password for user:", email)
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Incorrect password!')

        token = generate_jwt(user)

        response = Response(
            {'status': 'success', 'jwt': token}, 
            status=200
        )
        response.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True)
        print("User logged in successfully and JWT token set in cookie")
        return response

# View to get authenticated user details
class UserView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]

    def get(self, request):
        print("Inside UserView: Fetching user details")
        user = request.user
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=200)

# View for user logout
class LogoutView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]

    def post(self, request):
        print("Inside LogoutView: Logging out user")
        response = Response({'message': 'success'}, status=200)
        response.delete_cookie('jwt')
        print("User logged out successfully and JWT cookie deleted")
        return response

# New View to check if the user is logged in
class IsLoggedInView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]

    def get(self, request):
        print("Inside IsLoggedInView: Checking login status")
        user = request.user
        token = generate_jwt(user)
        return Response({'is_logged_in': True, 'jwt': token}, status=200)

Error Message
User logged in successfully and JWT token set in cookie
[28/Oct/2024 13:48:24] "POST /users/login HTTP/1.1" 200 166
Forbidden: /users/logout
[28/Oct/2024 13:48:39] "POST /users/logout HTTP/1.1" 403 29


In your logout operation (on the Flutter side), you're deleting the JWT right before you're trying to read it into the request to /logout.
    await prefs.remove('jwt'); // <-- Delete JWT

    // Optionally call the logout API
    final token = prefs.getString('jwt'); // <-- Attempt to retrieve JWT

Since the JWT has been removed, token becomes null. Which in turn means that the JWT header for the request going to Django doesn't contain a valid bearer token and that causes the HTTP 403.
You can verify by commenting out the line that deletes the JWT on the client-side, or by logging the value of the JWT header on the request that ends up in /logout.

I did and it still gives me the same result.

Wipe localstorage and cookies, print the token in the code for both /login and /logout, then log in and then logout. Check that the logged tokens are the same in both views.
